# Error con infe0 al grabar datos en tabla Mysql con python

Tags: mysql, python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Tengo un dataframe python con la siguiente estructura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y pretendo grabar estos datos a una tabla llamada "seasonalwindows" en una BBDD de Mysql. Estoy introduciendo el siguiente código:

```
wi.to_sql("seasonalwindows",conn,if_exists="replace")
```

pero me sale el error:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'infe0' in 'field list'") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO seasonalwindows (`index`, `Ticker`, `CodWindow`, `RtdadTotal`, `RtdadMedia`, `Sharpe`, `Rating`, `DiaIni`, `MesIni`, `DiaFin`, `MesFin`, `Porcalza`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: ((0, '2HR_FSE', 1010125, -15.132999999999994, -1.2653653846153834, -1.04, -59.0, 1, 1, 26, 1, 0.5555555555555556), (1, '2HR_FSE', 1260211, 46.716, 3.5284487179487183, 4.69, 64.0, 26, 1, 12, 2, 0.5555555555555556), (2, '2HR_FSE', 2120214, -5.716999999999999, -0.5213589743589742, -3.59, -59.0, 12, 2, 15, 2, 0.5370370370370371), (3, '2HR_FSE', 2150223, 19.799999999999997, 1.5053653846153843, 6.11, 62.0, 15, 2, 24, 2, 0.5277777777777778), (4, '2HR_FSE', 2240323, -63.65100000000002, -5.1995495337995346, -3.39, -55.0, 24, 2, 24, 3, 0.4777777777777778), (5, '2HR_FSE', 3240514, 110.908, 9.962610606060606, 4.57, 70.0, 24, 3, 15, 5, 0.48148148148148145), (6, '2HR_FSE', 5150606, -35.575, -2.93565675990676, -3.71, -57.0, 15, 5, 7, 6, 0.4523809523809524), (7, '2HR_FSE', 6070624, 27.777000000000008, 2.418203962703963, 4.24, 62.0, 7, 6, 25, 6, 0.4583333333333333)  ... displaying 10 of 29261 total bound parameter sets ...  (29259, 'ZOT', 10291108, 24.187999999999995, 0.8290364163372855, 2.71, 61.0, 29, 10, 9, 11, 0.5185714285714286), (29260, 'ZOT', 11091118, -23.233999999999995, -1.0927904710144927, -4.99, -59.0, 9, 11, 19, 11, 0.5170068027210885))] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Me dice que estoy intentando grabar una columna "infe0" pero ni existe ni la encuentro por ningún lado.
¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?. Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Tienes filas con alguna celda con valor `inf` o `-inf` (`numpy.inf`)?

Comment: No, no he encontrado ninguna celda con esos valores. Lo que he hecho es añadir una columna más a la tabla llamada 'infe0'. Es un poco chapuza pero funciona de momento, hasta que encuentre el verdadero motivo.

Comment: Que raro... Por cierto, ¿la query te agrega algo a esa columna?

Comment: No. No agrega nada a esa columna